# How to color polygons based on attribute in QGIS 3.8?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, style

I want to color polygons (fill color) based on an integer attribute (named "fold", ranging 1-5). It was so simple in older versions of QGIS (2.x), but now I installed version 3.8 and I am clueless (see the screenshot). I went to `Layer Properties` as usual, looking for the `Style` tab, which is no longer there, so I ended up in similar `Symbology` tab, but I don't see a way how to do it here.

[image]

---

PS: giving up, had to go back to the simplicity of good old QGIS 2.8

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In QGIS 3.8 (your first image), the `Single symbol` is a **drop-down menu** which is where you can select to categorise your layer:

[image: Symbology options]

Comment: Oh, thanks! Missed that one! :-)

Comment: @Tomas - Most welcome! Glad it helped :)